# PostgeSQL query in Python : how to pass dynamic parameter?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to create a dynamic PostgreSQL query in Python:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

V_ID=111

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="xxxx", port = 5432, database="xxxx", user="xxxxx", password="xxx")

df= pd.read_sql_query 
("""SELECT u.user_name, sum(s.sales_amount)
FROM public.users u left join public.sales s on u.id=s.user_id
WHERE USER_ID = v_ID
Group by u.user_name""",con=conn)
df.head()
```

When I set a fixed ID then a query ran fine, but if I set a variable "V_ID", then get an error.

Help me please, how to properly place a variable within a query...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string formatting to pass the value in the query string. You can read more about string formatting here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

```
v_ID = "v_id that you want to pass"

query = """SELECT u.user_name, sum(s.sales_amount)
FROM public.users u left join public.sales s on u.id=s.user_id
WHERE USER_ID = {v_ID}
Group by u.user_name""".format(v_ID=v_ID)

df= pd.read_sql_query(query ,con=conn)
```

As mentioned by @Adrian in the comments, **string formatting is not the right way** to do this.

More details here: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html), params can be list, tuple or dict.

> The syntax used to pass parameters is database driver dependent. Check
> your database driver documentation for which of the five syntax
> styles, described in PEP 249’s paramstyle, is supported. Eg. for
> psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use params={‘name’ : ‘value’}.

Here is how you can do this in the case of psycopg2.

```
v_ID = "v_id that you want to pass"

query = """SELECT u.user_name, sum(s.sales_amount)
FROM public.users u left join public.sales s on u.id=s.user_id
WHERE USER_ID = %(v_ID)s
Group by u.user_name"""

df= pd.read_sql_query(query ,con=conn, params={"v_ID":v_ID})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm a little confused where do I put a number? Initially v_ID ="111" or in format : .format(v_ID=111) ??

Comment: you have to write it in the first line only, like v_ID="111", please consider upvoting my answer if it helps.

Comment: The reasons why you should not use this method: [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Instead use the `params` argument to [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) to pass in the value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you for mentioning this, I have edited my answer. You can upvote it again if you think that could help others now.